# Please Help! Invalid CAPTCHA + City/town "Invalid"?

Tags: visas, europe, money

everyone. I'm trying to register with Hosteljobs.net -- I'll be backpacking through Europe, and need a work/trade exchange -- and I keep getting an error message:

1st: "CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected"
2nd: "City/town is invalid"

The 2nd one is the one that just won't go away. Hosteljobs.net has no help or contact info, not even an email, so I'm stymied. I've cleared cookies, cache, opened and closed browsers, and tried a different browser.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I had no idea where else to post it. Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: There's a forum on the website, have you tried asking there?

Comment: There's a tool called WHOIS you can use to get information about a website and it's owner. I found a technical contact for that site listed in their WHOIS info. I'm not going to post it here, but you should be able to come up with an e-mail address if you Google 'whois lookup' and use one of the tools you get in the search results. More info on WHOIS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travelling.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try WHOIS...I don't think I can use the website's forum without registering first, but I'll check again.